# What does it mean to add functions $f$ and $g$ without $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I can verify all the axioms, but I don't understand them. For example, the axiom of commutativity:

$$f(x)+g(x)=(f+g)(x)=(g+f)(x)=g(x)+f(x).$$

If the above is correct, what does it mean to add $f$ and $g$ without $x$? (e.g. add exponential function to square root function)

P.S. I'm teaching myself linear algebra and the book does not have a solution manual, so my question might be ridiculously easy! Apologize in advance.

Comment: The sum of two functions $f$ and $g$ is the function $h$ such that for all $x$, $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$.  This function $h$ is denoted by $f+g$.

Comment: So how do we know that f(x) + g(x) = g(x) + f(x)? In other words, If h(x)=f(x)+g(x)=g(x)+f(x), I did nothing to verify the first axiom but changed some notations. If that's true, then what does it mean to verify the axioms, then, if all we have to do is to restate them? If that's not true, then f+g is not simply f(x)+g(x).

Comment: $f(x)+g(x)=g(x)+f(x)$ for all $x$ by commutativity of addition for **numbers**. (One presumably doesn't have to prove that ordinary addition is commutative.)

Comment: Well as @michael-albanese, pointed out f(x) and g(x) are just numbers as well. So at the first of the equality we have numbers, and also at the end. In the middle, we've defined (f+g)(x) to be h(x) which is also a number. So what one must do if one does not have to verify the ordinary addition is commutative?

Comment: Wait, shouldn't I go like this: (f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=g(x)+f(x)=(g+f)(x); because in this case, I'm not just swapping numbers!

Comment: That's fine. And you are using the commutativity of ordinary addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f$ is a function, whereas $f(x)$ is the value of the function $f$ at the point $x$ in the domain of $f$.

The point is that while we are quite comfortable with the notion of adding real numbers to obtain a new one, we have to decide what we mean by adding functions. First of all, the sum of two functions should again be a function (just like the sum of two real numbers is a real number). So what is the function obtained by adding $g$ to $f$, which we denote by $f+g$? Well, a function is determined by its values, so we need to specify $(f+g)(x)$. Now we *define*

$$(f+g)(x) := f(x) + g(x).$$

Note that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are real numbers, so we know what it means to add them. As before, $f+g$ is the name of the function, and $(f + g)(x)$ is the value of the function $f + g$ at the point $x$ in its domain. But what is its domain? Well, $f$ and $g$ are both defined on $[0, 1]$, so we take the domain of $f + g$ to be $[0, 1]$ as well. More generally, we take the domain of $f + g$ to be $\operatorname{Dom}(f)\cap\operatorname{Dom}(g)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f+g$ is just a symbol to denote the resulting function given by $f(x)+g(x)$.

e.g.
$f(x)=\sin x$

$g(x)=x$

$(f+g)(x)=\sin x+x$